# $g(k)=\ln(\frac{(kv_1+x_1)(kv_2+x_2)}{(kv_1+y_1)(kv_2+y_2)})$ is locally monotonic？

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Suppose:

$k\in I\subset\mathbb R$,

$x,y,v\in \mathbb R^2$.

$v=(v_1,v_2)$ is a unit vector.

$f$ is a real function with two variables. $f(x)=\ln x_1+\ln x_2$.

$\alpha=kv+x$, $\beta=kv+y$

$g(k)=f(\alpha)-f(\beta)$.

We want to know that whether there exists a constraint set $X$, which is a subset of $\mathbb R^2$, satifying the following conditions: for any unit vector $v$, and any $k,x,y$ s.t. $\alpha\in X$ and $\beta\in X$, the function $g(k)$ is always decreasing or increasing in $k$.

---

Suppose that $g(k)$ is monotonic, then, when we fix the $v,x,y$, one of the following three conditions must hold for any $k$:

(1). $g'(k)>0$,

(2). $g'(k)=0$,

(3). $g'(k)<0$.

Although it seems obvious that such $X$ always exists, I highly doubt its existence.

---

I will start with taking the derivative:

$$g'(k)=\frac{v_1}{v_1k+x_1}+\frac{v_2}{v_2k+x_2}-\frac{v_1}{v_1k+y_1}-\frac{v_2}{v_2k+y_2}$$

Comment: I don't understand what properties $X$ is supposed to satisfy. If $kv+x\in X$ for any $x$, this means $X=\mathbb R^2.$ if it is only for a specific $x$, please make this clearer eg there exists $x_0$ such that...or maybe what you meant was to put the 'for all $k,v,x,y$ ' up front

Comment: @CalvinKhor $X$ is a constraint set for $kv+x$ and $kv+y$. We want to find constraint set $X$, such that if we force the $kv+x$ to fall within the constraint set, $g(k)$ is monotonic. I understand that this English language is not so clear. Do you know a better way to express this question?